# Can I use custom delegate method in Where method of Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, delegates

```
Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate);
```

I pass parameter to Where method as follows: `f => f.Id > 4`.
Can I pass a delegate method instead of `f.Id > 4`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

The Entity Framework needs to be able to **see** everything that is being attempted.

So if you simply did something like this:

```
queryable.Where(f => DelegateFunc(f));
```

Where the definition of DelegateFunc looks like this:

```
public bool DelegateFunc(Foo foo)
{
   return foo.Id > 4;
}
```

The Entity Framework has no way of peering inside the delegate, to crack it open and convert it to SQL.

All is not lost though.

If your goal is to re-use common filters etc you can do something like this instead:

```
public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> DelegateExpression{
   get{
       Expression<Func<Foo,bool>> expr = f => f.Id > 4;
       return expr;
   }
}

queryable.Where(DelegateExpression);
```

Comment: You are wrong, Alex. I pass to Where method as follows: "queryable.Where(f => DelegateFunc);" instead of "queryable.Where(f => DelegateFunc(f));". The statement executed successfully but it returned an Enumerable not Queryable.

Comment: I beg to differ. Generally when executing a filter you want to convert it to SQL. Getting an IEnumerable proves that you are NOT executing the filter in the database, instead LINQ to objects it taking over, and you are retrieving every record in the database and filtering in memory. Might work okay in testing, but once you have a lot of data it will perform awfully. Essentially you are using EF only to materialize entities, which is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Your comment is very useful, Alex. It has shown the defect of performance in my way. Instead of passing a delegate method, I will pass an Expression<TSource, Func<Tsource, TResult>>, which is returned by a method. In that method I can custom the condition.

Comment: Alex, why do you know LINQ will take every record in the database and filtering in memory? where did you read article, blog or documentation?

Comment: I worked on the Entity Framework product team at Microsoft. But more importantly if you don't have an query as an expression there is no way to convert it to SQL. That is why LINQ and expressions was invented. Oh and BTW I think I deserve an accept here!

Comment: +1 I wish I had stumbled upon this earlier. I learned it the hard way when I had implemented a RepositoryPattern API with a Where filterCriteria accepted as a parameter - the context.Entity.Where(filterCritera) would load all the records and then perform filtering!! Shocking. Just changed the API to accept an Expression wrapping the filterCriteria and it works as expected...

Comment: Is there a good way to combine these, or do you simply chain them?  i.e. so you can use self-documenting names for different parts of an expression and combine them. e.g. if you had expressions `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> IsActive` and `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> CreatedThisWeek` would the best way to combine them be `queryable.Where(IsActive).Where(CreatedThisWeek)`, or does this if your database had an index on creation date rather than status would this risk poor performance?  Also, could you do an `or` instead of an `and` like this?

Comment: (for others hitting this thread; asked about multiple expressions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074642/combine-multiple-linq-expressions)