# LINQ, Unable to create a constant value of type XXX. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my application I have Lecturers and they have list of Courses they can teach and when I'm deleting a course I want to remove connection to lecturers. Here's the code:

```
public void RemoveCourse(int courseId)
{
    using (var db = new AcademicTimetableDbContext())
    {
        var courseFromDb = db.Courses.Find(courseId);

        var toRemove = db.Lecturers
                        .Where(l => l.Courses.Contains(courseFromDb)).ToList();

        foreach (var lecturer in toRemove)
        {
            lecturer.Courses.Remove(courseFromDb);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I get

> NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type `Course`. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what kind of relation is between `Lecturer` and `Course`? Is it 1-to-n or n-to-n?

Comment: Related: [Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18929483/456814).

Comment: Related: [Unable to create a constant value - only primitive types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10862491/456814).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can't use `Contains` with non-primitive values. Do

```
Where(l => l.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseId).Contains(courseId)
```

(or the Id field you use).

Comment: Great answer @gert-arnold ! I was led here with the same error message, but I was using `Join` with a calculated value instead of the contains method. In this case, I only needed to enumerate the context results before performing the join.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a DbContext, you can query the .Local collection, and the == operator will work also with objects:

```
public void RemoveCourse(int courseId)
{
    using (var db = new AcademicTimetableDbContext())
    {
        var courseFromDb = db.Courses.Find(courseId);

        db.Lecturers.Load() //this is optional, it may take some time in the first load

        //Add .Local to this line
        var toRemove = db.Lecturers.Local 
                        .Where(l => l.Courses.Contains(courseFromDb)).ToList();

        foreach (var lecturer in toRemove)
        {
            lecturer.Courses.Remove(courseFromDb);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The .Local is an ObservableCollection, so you can compare anything you like inside it (not limited to SQL queries which don't support object comparison). Just to make sure you get all your objects in the .Local collection you can call the db.Lecturers.Load() method before calling .Local, which brings all database entries into the Local collection.

Answer (score 1):

The `Courses` collection of below line should be null or empty.

```
 var toRemove = db.Lecturers
                        .Where(l => l.Courses.Contains(courseFromDb)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you pass a `Func<T, bool>` to Where() as a way to write a dynamic condition like here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784005/can-i-use-custom-delegate-method-in-where-method-of-entity-framework)
For some reason the delegate can't be translated to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare complex type, if you have not specified what you mean for equality.

As exception detail says, you need to check primitive values (like Integer in your case).

And better to use `Any()` method instead.

```
var toRemove = db.Lecturers
     .Where(l => l.Courses.Any(p=>p.Id == courseFromDb.Id)).ToList();
```