# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. I can't seem to fix it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access the Id of a User (models provided below). 
A user has a list of Posts.
When editing a Post I am trying to Jump back to the User Detail action. So I need to access the Id of the user whom the post belongs to.
here is the error I get:

> "Unable to create a constant value of type 'MiniReesha.Models.Post'.
>   Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context."

here's the code:

```
 public ActionResult EditPost(int id)
 {
         var post = _context.Post.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
         if (post == null)
         return HttpNotFound();

         var user = _context.User.Single(u => u.Posts.Contains(post)); //error here
         var viewModel = new EditPostViewModel
         {
              User = user,
              Post = post,
              PostTypes = _context.PostType.ToList()
         };
         return View(viewModel);
}

My Models: 

 public class User
 {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Username { get; set; }
      public string Password { get; set; }
      public int Phone { get; set; }
      public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
 }
 public class Post
 {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public int Phone { get; set; }
      public PostType PostType { get; set; }

      [Display(Name ="Catagory")]
      public byte PostTypeId { get; set; }

 }
 public class PostType
 {
      public byte Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Any help would be much appreciate it

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929483/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-ty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ, Unable to create a constant value of type XXX. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405568/linq-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-xxx-only-primitive-types-or-enu)